# Search after multiple criterias with mailkit doesn't work

Tags: c#, mailkit

I have an application that must send some notification emails. After A time if I didn;t get a reply to that mail I must send a reply. Problem appears on the third reply cause the new reply will be sent for both emails sent before. Below are the functions I;ve tried..but none of them seems to work:

```
        SearchQuery.BodyContains(mailid).And(SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))

      SearchQuery.BodyContains(mailid).And(SearchQuery.SentAfter(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))

      SearchQuery.BodyContains(mailid).And(SearchQuery.SentSince(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-10))
```

How can I make to take only the emails sent after the time I give?

Answer (score 2):

IMAP's SEARCH functionality (especially with regards to timespan resolution) is very limited, so you'll probably need to write some client-side logic to filter the messages down to what you actually hope to find.

Start with `SearchQuery.BodyContains(mailid)` - does that return a list of messages including the one you expect to find?

If not, don't use that search.

To do client-side searching, I would recommend starting with a `folder.Fetch()` call of whatever subset of messages you can limit it to (and probably fetching at least `MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId`). The `Envelope` will give you most of the common message headers that you can then check.

For example:

```
var uidsWithMailId = folder.Search (SearchQuery.BodyContains (mailid));
var items = folder.Fetch (uidsWithMailId, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope);
var tenMinutesAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes (-10);
var matches = new UniqueIdSet ();
foreach (var item in items) {
    // check if the message was sent within the last 10 minutes
    if (item.Envelope.Date >= tenMinutesAgo) {
        // add the message UID to our list of matches
        matches.Add (item.UniqueId);
    }
}
```